# Variable data not retained to bind in HTML even after assigning data to it inside a subscribe() function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular4-httpclient

I have below **app-product.ts** code written as below:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'app-product',
   template: `
    <div>
      <h2>{{products.prod_name | uppercase}} Details</h2>
      <div><span>Description: </span>{{products.prod_desc}}</div>
    </div>`
 })

export class ProductComponent {

   products:any = [];

   constructor(public rest: RestService){ this.getProducts() }

   getProducts() {
     this.products = [];
     this.rest.getProducts().subscribe((data: {}) => {
     console.log(data); // data is printing in console
      this.products = data; // tried keeping debugger here 
   });
}
```

In the above code I am able to print the data in console but the variable products is not accessible in my template.
I also tried to keep a debugger at the point and I tried to print the products but it was showing as undefined every time.

Below is my angular service file for consuming REST API using Http Client as below:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class CarApiService {

  getProducts(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(endpoint + 'products').pipe(
    map(this.extractData));
  }
}
```

I also tried to analyse if there is any callback issues in the code but could not figure what is the real cause of this problem.

I also tried looking into few threads like:
[component variables inside a RxJS subscribe() function are undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39899595/component-variables-inside-a-rxjs-subscribe-function-are-undefined)
but could not find any help. Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: `<div *ngFor='let product of products'><h2>{{product.prod_name | uppercase}} Details</h2><div><span>Description: </span>{{product.prod_desc}}</div></div>`
Use this template to iterate array in html.

Comment: @JavascriptHuppTechnologies i am  not able to access products inside an HTML. its only showing when you hover on debugger but when you print it its not.

Comment: Sorry i am not getting what you are trying to say but if you have added debugger before `this.products = data;` and expecting to view in html then it should not. Try removing debugger and see what's happen with answer below added that same as my comment.

Comment: i meant to say i have kept a breakpoint in chrome debugging and checked, it was showing value only on hover but the same data is not printing inside a HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the service was in other module i had to create single sharing tree for access that return values.
So the code must be placed inside the export shared module block as below:

```
static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
return {
  ngModule: SharedModule
};
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your are trying to use `product` in template (`*ngIf="product"`) while the data is inside `products` variable.

and, you should call `getProducts()` function to fetch the values inside your array variable.

Import OnInit Interface and call the fucntion:

```
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {

   products:any = [];

   constructor(public rest: RestService){}

   ngOnInit() {
          this.getProducts();
   }
   getProducts() {
     this.products = [];
     this.rest.getProducts().subscribe((data: {}) => {
     console.log(data); // data is printing in console
      this.products = data; // tried keeping debugger here 
   });
}
```

### update due comment

if you want show array in your template you have to iterate over the array:

```
template: `
    <div *ngFor='let product of products'>
      <h2>{{product.prod_name | uppercase}} Details</h2>
      <div><span>Description: </span>{{product.prod_desc}}</div>
    </div>`
```

Comment: Problem  is i am not able to retrieve products in html

Comment: Take a look and the second part of the answer @Onera

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component({
   selector: 'app-product',
   template: `
   <div *ngFor='let product of products'>
      <h2>{{product.prod_name | uppercase}} Details</h2>
      <div><span>Description: </span>{{product.prod_desc}}</div>
   </div>`
 })

export class ProductComponent {

   products:{}[] = [];

   constructor(public rest: RestService){ this.getProducts() }

   getProducts() {
     this.products = [];
     this.rest.getProducts().subscribe((data: {}[]) => {
     this.products = data;
     console.log(this.products); // this should not be undifind
   });
}
```

otherwise check your spelling